# Windows system DSN. Как запретить пользователю создавать DSN подключения?

Tags: windows, devops

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как можно запретить пользователю системы Windows добавлять DSN подключения в ODBS Data Source Administrator.[Скриншот с ODBS Data Source Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cSWL.png)

Comment: Ну вообще-то у обычного пользователя не должно быть прав на создание системного DSN, кажется... в крайнем случае запрети запуск odbcad32.exe.

Comment: ну мы же знаем, что в Windows обычный пользователь это Администратор.